# Display many lines of errors messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, model-view-controller, alert, custom-errors

Hi i use alert to flash a message when a gossip was created or not. Here is my controller :

```
class GossipsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @gossips = Gossip.all
  end

  def show
    @gossip = Gossip.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @error = false
  end

  def create
    @gossip = Gossip.new(title: params[:title], content: params[:content], user: User.find(182))

    if @gossip.save
      flash[:success] = "success"
      redirect_to gossips_path 
    else
      flash[:danger] = @gossip.errors.full_messages[0]
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

But with this way the alert when gossips fail to create display only one error. I've tried to remove the `[0]` but the display is the following :

---

["Title can't be blank", "Title is too short (minimum is 3 characters)", "Content can't be blank"]

---

And I want an alert like this :

---

Error

• Title can't be blank

• Title is too short (minimum is 3 characters)

• Content can't be blank

---

Here it's my model :

```
class Gossip < ApplicationRecord
    validates_presence_of :title, :content
    validates :title, length: { in: 3..14 }

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :labelings
    has_many :tags, through: :labelings
end
```

Comment: Isn't that list style the default way to display errors when a validation fails?  Do you have these fields being validated by the Model, or some other way?

Comment: I've add my model in the question above

Comment: Ok so if those validations fail it should display in that list style with the boilerplate code Rails uses.  Can you post your view file please?

Comment: if i try this : `flash[:danger] = @gossip.errors.full_messages` that return me an alert with this : `["Title can't be blank", "Title is too short (minimum is 3 characters)", "Content can't be blank"]` too

Comment: That return me an array of error instead a list

Comment: you can join array elements, like `@gossip.errors.full_messages.join('<br />')` ... if you don't mind not having the bullets..